# Set file name with * as variable batch script

Tags: variables, batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file that i'm having issues with. I need to find the name of a file, then set it to a variable. Then I will use this to pass it onto a vbs script to further look into the file. The name of the file is logfile_date_time.log but the time varies depending on what time is starts. The point of the batch file is to find out the last modified date of this file.

```
set fordate=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%

set filename=c:\logfile_%fordate%_*.log

if exist %filename% (goto exist) else (goto noexist)

:exist

vbsscript.vbs /file:%filename%

goto end

:noexist

file doesn't exist code blah blah

:end

pause
```

I had to modify the names of folders and remove some code for security purposes since this is for work.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
set "last_modified="
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /tw /o-d /b^| findstr /r /i /c:"logfile_[0-9][0-9]*_.log"') do (
 do set "last_modified=%%~dpfnxf"
 goto :break_loop
)
:break_loop

if defined last_modified echo file %last_modified% exist ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it doesn't expand the wildcard character (`*`), and your VBScript probably doesn't handle wildcards in filenames by itself (the `FileSystemObject` methods for instance don't). If the file you want to process is the only one matching your pattern, you could do something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "fordate=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%"

pushd C:\
for %%f in (logfile_%fordate%_*.log) do vbsscript.vbs /file:"%%~ff"
popd
```